# Specifying Query and template parameters in POSTMAN

Tags: soapui, postman

I moved from SOAPUI to Postman for API testing and can't find a way to specify parameters as `Query` or `template` in Postman.

SOAPUI gives you an option to specify the type of parameter in its parameter table. 
[image]

But in Postman, it just gets recognized as `Query` parameter (appended to URL)

[image]

Need to find a way to specify parameter as template parameter in POSTMAN

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Postman you need to use `:variable` to specify a template parameter. So in your example, your request URL would look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/database/:databaseID
```

After declaring your URL this way, you would click on Params where you should see your key, "databaseID" in this case, and you can provide any value, including any global or environment variable.

Comment: Thanks @SiKing, but where would I declare the variable and its value? In the Environment variables? or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If you got error 40043 .

You just check your username or channel in tab **headers**

if you don't have --> put it and try to send the request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).